# Lion connecting rails to postgresql , with ssd boot drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-lion, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to use postgresql with my rails development on Lion. My machine is currently set to boot from a solid state and store /home folder on a seperate hd. I'm able to create users for postgres fine using the

> createuser

command

but when ever i try to create a db using rake

```
rake db:create
```

i get this error

> could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running
>   locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in
>   `initialize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in`
>   new'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in
>   `connect'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:312:in`initialize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in
>   `new'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in`
>   postgresql_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in
>   `new_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in`
>   checkout_new_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in
>   `block (2 levels) in checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in`
>   loop'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in
>   `block in checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in
>   `checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in`
>   connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in`
>   retrieve_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:110:in`
>   rescue in create_database'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:54:in
>   `create_database'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in`
>   block (5 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:151:in
>   `local_database?'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in`
>   block (4 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:19:in
>   `each_value'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:19:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `call'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
>   `each'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in`
>   execute'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in`
>   invoke'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
>   `invoke_task'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `each'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   block in top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in`
>   top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in
>   `block in run'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in
>   `run'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in`
>   '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in
>   `load'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in`
>   ' Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
>   "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"alpha_development", "pool"=>5,
>   "username"=>"alpha", "password"=>nil} could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused    Is the server running locally and accepting
>     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in
>   `initialize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in`
>   new'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in
>   `connect'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:312:in`initialize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in
>   `new'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in`
>   postgresql_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in
>   `new_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in`
>   checkout_new_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in
>   `block (2 levels) in checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in`
>   loop'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in
>   `block in checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in
>   `checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in`
>   connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in`
>   retrieve_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:110:in`
>   rescue in create_database'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:54:in
>   `create_database'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in`
>   block (5 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:151:in
>   `local_database?'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in`
>   block (4 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:19:in
>   `each_value'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:19:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `call'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
>   `each'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in`
>   execute'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in`
>   invoke'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
>   `invoke_task'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `each'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   block in top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in`
>   top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in
>   `block in run'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in
>   `run'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in`
>   '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in
>   `load'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in`
>   ' Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
>   "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"alpha_test", "pool"=>5,
>   "username"=>"alpha", "password"=>nil} could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused    Is the server running locally and accepting
>     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in
>   `initialize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in`
>   new'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1076:in
>   `connect'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:312:in`initialize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in
>   `new'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in`
>   postgresql_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in
>   `new_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in`
>   checkout_new_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in
>   `block (2 levels) in checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in`
>   loop'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in
>   `block in checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in
>   `checkout'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in`
>   connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in`
>   retrieve_connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:110:in`
>   rescue in create_database'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:54:in
>   `create_database'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in`
>   block (5 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:151:in
>   `local_database?'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33:in`
>   block (4 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:19:in
>   `each_value'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:19:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `call'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
>   `each'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in`
>   execute'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in`
>   invoke'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
>   `invoke_task'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `each'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   block in top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in`
>   top_level'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in
>   `block in run'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in
>   `run'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in`
>   '
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in
>   `load'
>   /Volumes/Lion/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in`
>   ' Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
>   "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"alpha_production", "pool"=>5,
>   "username"=>"alpha", "password"=>nil}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Lion or SSD.

Please check if your pgsql is running or not first.

```
netstat -tan | grep LISTEN
```

PostgreSQL should be listening on 5432 port by default.